# Moving sensitive logic out of browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've made a nice little math quiz app in rails 5 that generates random math algebra problems to the user. All of the random variables and checking to see if user's answers are correct is done in the view with javascript. I want to move this logic to the backend so the user can't cheat with browser tools like inspect. Not sure where to put this in a rails app or how it would work?
Does it go in rails/lib or do I make an ajax call?  The problems are not hard coded in a database, just randomly generated. So I need to generate some random numbers in the backend send to the view to display something like 3x - 2 = 5x + 12. And then have the user's answer checked against the solution for this random problem in the backend and send info back to front-end quiz form which is keeping track of score.

Answer (score 0):

See [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-directory-structure.htm) is the basic rails folder structure and usage of each folder

Secondly, straight to the point You can write that kind of logic either in the controller(not recommended) or in the services(recommended)

I recommend to use services for that See [Here](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services) why